# Call multiple classes without if statements

Tags: c++, oop

This is just a quick question. I'm new to OOP.
I want to make 2 classes named Level1 and Level2

```
class Level1{
  //some code
};
class Level2{
  //some code
};
```

In int main() I want to call first or second class depending on the input of the user.

```
int main(){
  int choice;
  cin>>choice;
}
```

Now the first option that comes to mind is to make 2 if statements, like this:

```
int main(){
  int choice;
  cin>>choice;
  if(choice == 1){
    Level1 level;
  }
  else if(choice == 2){
    Level2 level;
  }
}
```

But is there some way to just add the int that the user just entered next to "Level"? Like this:

```
int main(){
  int choice;
  cin>>choice;
  Level(choice) level;
  //the int choice should add 1 or 2 near the Level class
}
```

Sorry If I'm bad at explaning

Comment: It seems like you want the input `int` to be used to decide the *name* of the class that is used. Is that correct? That's not actually possible in c++.

Comment: There are various way you could achieve a similar effect. A lot depends on how closely related the `Level1` and `Level2` classes are.

Comment: Oh I was thinking that too! Just making sure if there may be a way, thanks for the reply!

Comment: John I want to make a game with like 10 levels and I don't want to waste a lot of lines just typing the if statements for every case. Like on every level the coordantes of the player where to spawn is different.

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with these types? Are the two things similar? We don't have enough information.

Comment: – Asteroids With Wings, All the classes have the same variables but with different values

Comment: Then it seems all you need is a single class. You can have multiple objects of that class that have different values for each of the variables.

Comment: – cigien Then how can I add the value of the user input in the call of the object

Comment: There are various options. You could pass the value through a member function, for example. Consult whatever resources you're using, and read up on classes. It should be quite clear how to do this.

Comment: – cigien Oh, that makes sense! Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot, in C++, have functionality dependent on the name of something. C++ lacks reflection (by design). But there's various ways around it.

The OOP way would be:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Level
{
public:
    virtual void Load() {};
};

class Level1: public Level 
{
public:
    virtual void Load() {std::cout << "Level 1\n";};
};

class Level2: public Level 
{
public:
    virtual void Load() {std::cout << "Level 2\n";};
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Level> levels[2] = {std::make_shared<Level1>(), std::make_shared<Level2>()}; 

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;

    if (i >= 0 && i < 2)
    {
        levels[i]->Load();
    }
}
```

It uses polymorphism so that you have an array of pointers to various specialized object. This is good when you have different behaviours.

Templates would offer a different way. std::functions and lambdas would be another way.

But if the behaviour is always the same, use a single class.

Comment: Thanks for reply! In my game all do the same behaviour. But I will learn polymorphism , templates, lambdas for future projects. I saw some good videos about templates and lambdas at "The Cherno" youtube channel.